# Is there a way to reference a different cell changing each day depending on date?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So, I am trying to build a dashboard kinda thing in Google Sheets and in that, I have a cell that has to show a quote or a motto for the day (this is different for each day and has to change depending on the date). I have all 366 quotes for 2020 in a different sheet in the same Google sheets workbook.

I need to get a different quote every day and update it on the quote/motto cell from the quotes sheet.

I am noobie when it comes to sheets and it would be great if someone could guide me in getting this sorted out (I'm having sleepless nights because of this)

[image: This is the quotes sheet if you need the reference range]

Comment: Use random or get date of current

Comment: Oh, I figured out the solution. I used the LOOKUP function to access the quote corresponding to the date. Thanks

Comment: Hi Patrick, could you post your solution as an answer so other people can benefit from this question too?